# SELECT with temporary column with value based on other column

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have mysql table which schema resembles the json array below.

```
[
    { "id": 1, "firstName": "Charles Montgomery", "lastName": "Burns", "managerId": 12},
    { "id": 2, "firstName": "Bart", "lastName": "Simpson", "managerId": 1},
    { "id": 3, "firstName": "Marge", "lastName": "Simpson", "managerId": 1},
    { "id": 4, "firstName": "Lisa", "lastName": "Simpson", "managerId": 1},
    { "id": 5, "firstName": "Maggie", "lastName": "Simpson", "managerId": 1},
    { "id": 6, "firstName": "Homer", "lastName": "Simpson", "managerId": 4},
    { "id": 7, "firstName": "Ned", "lastName": "Flanders", "managerId": 4},
    { "id": 8, "firstName": "Krusty", "lastName": "The Clown", "managerId": 2},
    { "id": 9, "firstName": "Waylon", "lastName": "Smithers", "managerId": 2},
    { "id": 10, "firstName": "Ralph", "lastName": "Wiggum", "managerId": 5},
    { "id": 11, "firstName": "Itchy", "lastName": "", "managerId": 5},
    { "id": 12, "firstName": "Comic Book Guy", "lastName": "", "managerId": 4}
]
```

`managerId` field is self referencing foreign key to the `id` field.

I need to make a query which will add column on the fly with "managerName" computed from `id` field which will hold concatenated firstName and lastName.

Below is (simplified) query that I've tried. Question mark is placeholder filled by [mysql driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) (in nodejs):

```
SELECT * , 
(SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', firstName, lastName) FROM employee WHERE managerId = id ) as managerName
FROM employee WHERE employee.id = ?;
```

I realize this `WHERE managerId = id` is the place to look, but I honestly don't know what condition to place to match correct values.

Can anyone help?

**EDIT**
In case someone stumbles upon same thing, I've found [helpful article](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-self-join/). Even examples are similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LEFT JOIN is your friend. tra to use a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    e.*,
    CONCAT_WS(' ', m.firstName, m.lastName) AS managerName
FROM employee e WHERE e.employee.id = ?
LEFT JOIN  employee m ON e.managerId = m.id;
```

Comment: By 'e' and 'm' do you reference two different tables? This is all in one table.

Comment: @Ketus - yes i joined the same table, but i forget a "m" in my query. please try again

Comment: Thanks for response. I'm new to this syntax to I don't see error but Sql Workbench returns syntax error near "LEFT JOIN employee m ON e.managerId = m.id"

Comment: please look if you copyed it before i has saved compled

Comment: Sure, I refreshed the page to be sure.

Comment: I've got it. Somehow "FROM employee e" must be above LEFT JOIN

Comment: oh oh, this weather is not good for me. sorry, sorry. i will change it in my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111444/discussion-between-ketus-and-bernd-buffen).

Comment: I accept that it's very hot today, but why are we upvoting (and accepting) syntactical gibberish? Even after the edit, the OUTER JOIN will be nonsensical.